# Missing form tag from one table cell

Tags: php, forms, html-table

I've got a weird problem. With this code I'm generating a bunch of tables:

```
<a big form>
*code*
for ($g=1;$g<=$g_number;$g++){
    *some random code*
    echo"<div id='grupa$g' style='float:left;padding:2px;'><h3>Grupa $g</h3>
            <table border='1px' style='display:block; text-align:center';>
                <thead>
                    <th>Name</th><th>V.</th><th>Sets/th><th>m</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>";
    for ($p=0;$p<$no_of_items[$g];$p++){
               echo"<tr>
                        <td>".$components[$g][1][$p]."</td>
                        <td>".$components[$g][2][$p]."</td>
                        <td>".$components[$g][4][$p]."-".$components[$g][5][$p]."</td>
                        <td>".$components[$g][6][$p]."</td>
                        <td><form method='post' action='delete_from_groups.php'><input type=submit name=delete value='".$components[$g][0][$p]."'></input></form></td>
                    </tr>";
    }
           echo" </tbody>
            </table>";
    *random code*
}
*some more code*
</end of big form>
```

The rightmost column contains a button inside a form on each row. Everything works as intended, except for the first cell of that type in the first table. That cell contains just the button (named correctly) and all the other cells on that row contain the correct values, but that first cell that should contain a form doesn't have it. It's just

```
<td><input type="submit" value="411" name="delete"></input></td>
```

all the rest being as they should:

```
<td><form action="delete_from_groups.php" method="post"><input type="submit" value="412" name="delete"></input></form></td>
```

Could anyone explain why?

Comment: What creates `$components`?

Comment: components is created from some queries, but I don't think that its contains have any influence, especially because it has the correct values (in the example above the value 411 is the right value)